# YouTube not rendering correctly

Tags: chromium, youtube

I am attempting to run YouTube on Chromium. For some reason, the thumbnails don't load, and the videos don't play. My internet connection is good, and Windows loads the page correctly.

Why is Chromium doing this, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Does it load in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

We gonna make Chromium to create new settings to see if we can solve this **don't worry for your previous settings you will not lose them if it is not work.**

**Close Chromium**, use Firefox for now or take a photo or a screenshot of my answer before you close it.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal:

```
cd .config
mv chromium chromium_orig
```

**Do not close the terminal yet.**

**See** if Youtube works properly.

If indeed works like it should **close terminal** and change your settings as you prefer to Chromium

Done.

---

**If still not shows youtube like it should restore to your previous settings:**

**Close Chromium.**

In the opened terminal type:

```
rm -r chromium
mv chromium_orig chromium
```

**Try to update and reinstall Chromium:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall chromium-browser
```

Try again Chromium and see if the problem have been solved.

Comment: I don't think your package name is right. Please double check all of your commands. Also, I'd highly recommend you also read the [answer] page just to get a refresher.